# Combine duplicate rows and sum up the next column vba

Tags: vba

How do i find the duplicates in a cloumn and merge them as a single cell and 
    add their adjacent columns and show them as a single cell value?
    In short how do i convert table 1 to table 2 format?
   Table 1

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         54       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          13         |         43       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Table 2

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         88       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          13         |         43       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Below is the code i have tried. It just marks the duplicate values as duplicate and i am unable to sum up the values and show them in the previous cell

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & 
lastRow), 0)
If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
Cells(iCntr, 2) = "Duplicate"
End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried till now?

Comment: Is the `heading1` is sorted or it's random?

Answer (score 0):

This uses column C as a helper column, which is filled with a SumIF formula to sum up all values matching the Column A values, then delete column B and shift Column C into its place before removing duplicates to give you the desired outcome.

The following should do as you want:

```
Sub foo()
    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row with data
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Heading 2" 'add heading to column C
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = "=SUMIF(C[-2],RC[-2],C[-1])" 'enter formula to sum values of column B into column C
        Next i
    Sheet1.Range("C:C").Copy 'Copy values of column C
    Sheet1.Range("C:C").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 'paste as values on column C
    Range("B:B").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'Delete Column B and shift Column C to the left
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes ' Remove duplicates
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a solution. :) He wants to merge the duplicate values and Add the values

Comment: I have just tried and tested this and it does exactly as he requested...

Answer (score 0):

## Use a Pivot Table:

[image: pivot 1]

.

[image: pivot 2]

.
[image: pivot 3]

Or, **make the same Pivot Table with VBA:**

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Sheet1!R1C1:R4C2", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R1C4", TableName:="PivotTable1"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .PivotFields("Heading 1").Orientation = xlRowField
    .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Heading 2"), "Sum of Heading 2", xlSum
End With
```

☃